# UIPageViewController ignores Constraints when UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm working on an app for my culinary Blog and wanted to achieve a look and feel like on the Apple AppStore Application. In my *DashboardViewController*:**UIViewController** Class I added a *headerView*:**UIView** and a *scrollView*:**UIScrollView**. The *headerView* is populated with my *HeaderPageViewController*:**UIPageViewController** as seen below. The Constraints are set to achieve a parallax effect on scrolling. 
[image: View Hierarchy]

To get some Content inside the Views my *HeaderPageViewController*'s View gets an *imageContentView*:**UIImageView** which is populated at runtime with the recipes of the month. Of course I added the usual constraints to the *imageContentView*, so it has the same size as the *HeaderPageViewController.view*!

When initialising the *HeaderPageViewController* with `HeaderPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.PageCurl, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)` everything works fine. The Constraints of the *imageContentView* will be applied and the image grows and shrinks with it's ViewController inside the *headerView*. Whereas when I initialise the *HeaderPageViewController* with `HeaderPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)` the *imageContentView* won't change with the size of the *headerView*.

On the left side of that Image below you can see the effect using the initialiser with *UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.PageCurl*. On Scrolling the size of the headerPageViewController changes. on the right side you can see the result when setting *UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll* in the initialiser. I changed the BackgroundColor Property of the *HeaderPageViewController*, so you can better see the effect.

[image: Scrolling]

---

I think I can boil it down to the Pagination of the **UIPageViewController**. When Displaying the Pagination the black Area is immediately visible, showing the Pagination on it as seen below. When scrolling up the View that contains the Pagination scales with my constraints, but apparently this is not the same View as the one I applied my constraints to.

### [image: Pagination]

This is the Important part of the *DashboardViewController* including my **UIPageViewControllerDataSource** function declaration.

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    [...]

    func populateHeaderView() {
        let headerPageViewController:HeaderPageViewController = HeaderPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)
        //transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil
        headerPageViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        headerPageViewController.dataSource = self
        headerPageViewController.delegate = self
        let currentViewController:[UIViewController] = [self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)!]
        headerPageViewController.setViewControllers(currentViewController, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(headerPageViewController)
        let headerPageView:UIView = headerPageViewController.view
        headerPageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        headerPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        headerView.addSubview(headerPageView)
        headerPageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        var headerPageViewContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        headerPageViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerPageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: headerView,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        headerPageViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerPageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: headerView,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        headerPageViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerPageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: headerView,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        headerPageViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerPageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: headerView,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        self.view.addConstraints(headerPageViewContraints)
    }

    // MARK: UIPageViewController DataSource

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if var index:UInt = (viewController as! HeaderPageViewController).index {
            if (index == 0) {
                return nil
            }
            index--

            return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
        }
        return nil
    }

        func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if var index:UInt = (viewController as! HeaderPageViewController).index {
            index++
            if (Int(index) == headerRecipes.count) {
                return nil
            }
            return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
        }
        return nil
    }

    /*
    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return headerRecipes.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    */

    // MARK: UIPageViewController Helper

    func getReasonableRecipesForHeaderPageViewController() {
        if(headerRecipes.count == 0) {
            headerRecipes = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [Posts]
            if (headerRecipes.count > 3) {
                headerRecipes = Array(headerRecipes[0..<3])
            }
        }
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index:UInt) -> UIViewController? {
        if (headerRecipes.count == 0 || Int(index) >= headerRecipes.count) {
            return nil
        }

        let headerPageViewController:HeaderPageViewController = HeaderPageViewController()
        let recipe:Posts = headerRecipes[Int(index)] as Posts
        headerPageViewController.manageImageContentView(UIImageView(image: UIImage(data:recipe.featured_image!)))
        headerPageViewController.index = index
        return headerPageViewController
    }
}
```

Also there is the complete *HeaderPageViewController* Class, which subclasses the **UIPageViewController**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class HeaderPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var index:UInt?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func manageImageContentView(imageContentView:UIImageView) {
        imageView = imageContentView
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        var headerViewContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        headerViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        headerViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        headerViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        headerViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0))
        self.view.addConstraints(headerViewContraints)
    }

    override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

If anyone of you has a hint to which view I have to apply my constraints or where I made a dumb mistake, please tell me.

Comment: A friend of mine referred to the [bug Report](http://www.openradar.me/21728584), which assumes, that the UIPageViewController in UINavigationController does not update autolayout constraints for bottom layout. It sounds possible, that this bug also effects my Layout, even though it works fine with `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.PageCurl`.

Comment: The Bug is now reported in apples [Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com).